# Given initial condition and expected result calculate time in differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the equation

$$ x'(t) = -kx(t) $$

If $x(0)=238$ (grams) and i know that after $10$ hours the reduction would be a $20$% less, then how many time i would wait for get a reduction to $21$ grams?

I proceed like this:

$$\int \frac{dx}{x}=-\int kdt \implies x = C_1 e^{-kt}$$

So considering $x(0) = 238$ i have that $C_1=238$, so now if in $10$ hours i have a $20$% reduction:

$$ x(10) = 0.8x(0) \implies C_1e^{-10k}=0.8C_1 \implies k=\frac{ln|0.8|}{-10} $$

So now i could do:

$$21=238e^{-t \frac{ln|0.8|}{-10}} \implies ln|\frac{21}{238}|= -tln|0.8|$$

Getting that the result is $108.7976$ but i know this is wrong, and i don't know where i get the mistake

Comment: When you say "after $10$ hours the reduction would be a $20$," do you mean that after $10$ hours we should have $20$ grams or after $10$ hours we should have $20\%$ less?

Comment: Your value for $C_1$ and $k$ is right. And $x(10)=238e^{-10 \frac{ln|0.8|}{-10}}=190.4$. This is 80% of 238. $\color{blue}{\checkmark}$

Comment: yes, a 20% less, i have to find the time spend to get to 21 gr

Comment: You want to calculate how long you need to reduce 238 to 217(=238-21) ? Just solve the equation $217=238e^{t\cdot \frac{ln(0.8)}{10}}$ t is about 4.14